# Python to perl: itertools product to replace a char in string in each possible position

Tags: python, perl

The following python code enables me to take a string of words and replace spaces with hyphens in every possible combination:

```
from itertools import product

def dashed_combos(inputstring):
    words = inputstring.split()
    for combo in product(' -', repeat=len(words) - 1):
        yield ''.join(w for pair in zip(words, combo + ('',)) for w in pair)
```

This will produce the following combinations from the string `convert perl to-python`

```
'convert perl-to python'
'convert-perl to python'
'convert perl-to-python'
'convert-perl-to python'
'convert-perl-to-python'
```

I'm now trying to do exactly the same with perl. I've found a few modules that can produce the cartesian product (e.g. [Math::Cartesian::Product](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Cartesian::Product) and [nested loops from Algorithm::Loops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Loops#NestedLoops1)), although not being that familiar with perl I've struggled to get these to work to do what had worked so well in python. If anyone would be so kind as to help me here that would be great, as I've spent quite a while trying now, but with little joy.

Comment: What does the  `product()` function do?

Comment: @simbabque [DOC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)?

Comment: @ChakerBenhamed Thank you. I'm a perl guy. I don't know where to look for Python documentation. I think if OP is asking for help translating code it's useful to link to the documentation of the stuff they use.

Comment: @simbabque yes sorry about not linking to the python module. I'm not that bothered whether I have to use another implementation of the cartesian product in perl, though I presume that will still be the most efficient way of doing it. I simply need the same results that I get from the python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Math::Cartesian::Product](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Cartesian::Product) it's possible to almost exactly translate your code. You will find `zip` in [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#zip-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-ARRAY3).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Math::Cartesian::Product;
use List::MoreUtils 'zip';

sub dashed_combos {
  my @words = split / /, shift;
  my @permutations;
  foreach my $product ( cartesian { return @_  } ([ q{ }, q{-}]) x scalar @words - 1 ) {
    push @permutations, join q{}, grep { defined } zip @words, @$product;
  }
  return @permutations;
}

say for dashed_combos('convert perl to python' );
```

This will output:

```
convert perl to python
convert perl to-python
convert perl-to python
convert perl-to-python
convert-perl to python
convert-perl to-python
convert-perl-to python
convert-perl-to-python
```

Let's take a look at what I did:

- Functions in Perl get their arguments [in the array `@_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARG) (read: at-underscore). [`shift`ing](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) that array yields the first argument. Because `shift` acts on `@_` implicitly you can ommit it.
- Perl's [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) takes a regular expression as the delimiter to split on. We used `/ /`, which is a single space.
- The `cartesian` function exported by Math::Cartesian::Product takes a `BLOCK` and a bunch of array references. There is no comma after the `BLOCK`. That's shorthand for passing a code reference (lambda function).
- [q{} is a quote-like operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) that is identical to `''`, but the readability is better for stuff like a single space .
- The [`x` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators), when used on a list, repeats the list n times. The list we repeat has one element, the array reference with a space  and a dash `-` in it.
- Arrays in Perl will return the number of elements when forced into `scalar` context.
- `zip` from List::MoreUtils fills the smaller list with [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values) if the two arrays are not the same size. Since that will give warnings when `join`ed we need to [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) for only [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) (which is not `undef`).
- `@$product` is dereferencing an array reference to an array.

Comment: Thank you, and also great you could explain it so well.

Comment: I wasn't done explaining. Had to run. Will continue now.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `Algorithm::Combinatorics`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw( variations_with_repetition );
use List::MoreUtils qw( zip );

my $input_string = join ' ', @ARGV;
print "Input string is '$input_string'\n";

my $tokens = ' -';
my @parts = split /[$tokens]/, $input_string;

print "My string parts are : ", join (', ', map { "'$_'" } @parts) . "\n";
my @tokens_to_use = split //, $tokens;

my @combos = variations_with_repetition( \@tokens_to_use, scalar @parts - 1 );

for my $combo (@combos) {
    my $string_variety = join '', zip( @parts, @$combo );
    print $string_variety . "\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Input string is 'convert perl to-python'
My string parts are : 'convert', 'perl', 'to', 'python'
convert perl to python
convert perl to-python
convert perl-to python
convert perl-to-python
convert-perl to python
convert-perl to-python
convert-perl-to python
convert-perl-to-python
```

Comment: Thank you too. Works perfectly.